# How do I get the equivalent of the $\LaTeX$ \tag{} in Mathematica?

Tags: notebooks, formatting, latex

How do I get the equivalent of the $\LaTeX$ \tag{} in Mathematica?

$a+b=x \tag{1}$

I'm not necessarily asking how to use the $\LaTeX$ `\tag{}` itself in Mathematica, I'm just looking for some feature that will allow me to mark an equation like that.

Comment: [`CellLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabel.html) gets close but as `Right` is not a valid setting for [`CellLabelPositioning`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabelPositioning.html) it cannot, AFAIK, be made to look as you show.

Comment: There's also the Automatic Numbering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not think what you are asking for is possible. But you can do what you want by
numbering an equation in Mathematica like this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

do not know if this will meet your needs.

Using Mathematica like Latex is not really practical or useful. I found it is better to just use Latex for typesetting, and use Mathematica for doing the computation and analysis.

Comment: Yes. But I wasn't expecting to use $\LaTeX$ to do that. I was expecting for any alternative that would lead me to do that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 10):

As others have pointed out, automatic numbering is nicely taken care of through the built-in `DisplayFormulaNumbered` style. Custom numbering (both a separate [counter](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CounterAssignments.html) and [counting sequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CounterFunction.html)) can be introduced into [stylesheets](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateANewStyleInAStylesheet.html), for example, I have made a `Theorem` style before.

However, for a one off equation numbers / labels, like the $\LaTeX$ `\tag` option, you just want to manually set the `CellFrameLabels` option. This can be done using the [option inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) or by using `CellPrint` or [Show Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/ShowExpression.html). For example

```
CellPrint[Cell[BoxData[
   FormBox[RowBox[{"a", "+", "b", "=", "c"}], TraditionalForm]], 
  "DisplayFormula", CellFrameLabels -> {{None, "(1a)"}, {None, None}}]]
```

produces
[image: a+b=c]
selecting the cell and looking at the option inspector shows you
how you could edit this option with a GUI:

[image: option inspector]

---

However, referring to that equation using the standard [CellTags](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellTags.html) and [Automatic Numbering](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/AutomaticNumbering.html) / CounterBox combination seems to be a bit tricky... 
There might be a nice way of doing it, but nothing immediately comes to mind.