# How to include automatic references to cells styled with DisplayFormulaNumbered

Tags: text, style

Under the `Style` menu, there is an entry called `DisplayFormulaNumbered`.  It does exactly what it seems to suggest: it indexes the contents of the cell by an auto-incrementing number.  The numbering is updated throughout the notebook automatically.  For instance, if I have three formulas numbered `(1)`, `(2)` and `(3)`, and I delete `(2)`, Formula `(3)` automatically becomes Formula `(2)`.

But the references to Formula `(3)` in the text of the notebook are not updated automatically.  I have to manually change all of them.

Is there a way to automate this task?  (Sorry, I can't seem to give a better description of the problem.)

Comment: related [Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17342/125)

Comment: @kguler, thanks a lot for pointing that out.  So, unfortunately, ti seems that I am out of luck here.

Comment: If you want to reference a numbered DisplayFormula cell got to the menu Insert > Automatic Numbering...

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, please write your comment as an answer.  I would be glad to accept it--because it works!

Comment: ok I will when i have some time ...in the morning. I think that this has probably been asked and answered before. Here is one that may give you enough information: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19757/centered-automatic-numbering-of-figures